# Différence entre « station » et « gare »

Tags: sens, transports

Je me suis fait dire, plus d'une fois, qu'il faut dire « gare » lorsque l'on parle de l'endroit où s'arrête un train, mais « station » lorsque l'on parle d'un métro ou d'un autobus. Est-ce vrai? Et pourquoi?

Il n'y a pas nécessairement de construction pour attendre le train ou se procurer des billets : le train de banlieue que j'utilise n'a que deux de ces gares, aux terminus, ailleurs ce ne sont que des abri-bus et des machines à billets.

L'utilisation viendrait-elle du temps où il y avait, à chaque arrêt de train, une gare proprement dite, alors que les stations de métro et d'autobus peuvent être considérées que comme des débarcadères?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Peut-être y a-t-il des usages qui varient dans la francophonie sur les usages des mots « gare » et « station » ?

Je vais faire une synthèse du *Dictionnaire Culturel en Langue Française* qui décrit un usage que j'ai pu constaté en France, où le mot station ne semble plus employé dans le domaine ferroviaire, seuls sont employés « gare » et « halte ». Une halte SNCF est un simple débarcadère/embarcadère de voyageurs sans bâtiment ou vente de billets.

**Station** : « endroit aménagé pour l'arrêt des véhicules de transport public ; bâtiments et installations qu'il comporte...».
Suivent des exemples avec station de taxi, station de métro et station d'autobus et le dictionnaire signale que l'emploi de « station de chemin de fer » pour « gare » est vieilli de nos jours et qu'en langage moderne « station » s'emploie pour une gare de peu d'importance (avec un renvoi à halte).

**Gare** : 
Toujours dans le *Dictionnaire Culturel en Langue Française* j'apprends que dans le domaine ferroviaire en 1831 le mot désignait un « emplacement disposé sur une voie de chemin de fer pour le croisement des trains. Sens vieilli de nos jours.
 En 1835 a remplacé «embarcadère» et «débarcadère».  De nos jours **gare** « désigne l'ensemble des immeubles et installations établies aux stations des lignes de chemin de fer pour l'embarquement et le débarquement des voyageurs et des marchandises (par opposition aux simples stations ou haltes). »

**Halte** :
Toujours dans le *Dictionnaire Culturel en Langue Française* : « Point d'arrêt sur une ligne, où le train ne prend que les voyageurs, sans que soit prévu un temps d'arrêt déterminé (voir station) ».

---

Anecdote : Il existe en France au moins une gare SNCF qui contient le mot station :  [Mantes-Station](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gare_de_Mantes-Station) entre  les deux villes de Mantes-la-Jolie et de Mantes-la-Ville.

Comment: Les entrées pour [gare](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/gare) et [station](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/station) dans le TFLi sont similaires. Globalement _station_ est plus général et _gare_ plus spécialisé. _Gare_ comme lieu aménagé pour le croisement était employé pour la navigation fluviale avant son utilisation ferroviaire.

Comment: Il semble effectivement qu'il y a une différence dans l'usage de ces termes, puisque tous les points d'arrêt des différentes lignes de train de banlieue de la région de Montréal sont appelées des gares, alors que la vaste majorité devraient être des haltes, selon ces définitions.

Answer (score 5):

Station est utilisé dans "station de métro" et "station de taxi". On ne dit jamais "gare de métro" ou "gare de taxi" mais on dit "gare RER" puisqu'il s'agit de trains. "station d'autobus" me parait surtout utilisé au Québec. En France, c'est un "arrêt d'autobus", un "terminus", voire une gare routière s'il y a aussi des (auto)cars.

Il existe aussi au moins une "[gare autoroutière"](http://www.cc-paysdelimours.fr/gare-autoroutiere) où l'on va à pied prendre un car le long d'une autoroute.

Answer (score 0):

En Suisse, il n'y a pas de stations, sauf pour les taxis qui stationnent.

Les bus et les trams ont des arrêts et le métro de Lausanne à des gares.

Les trains n'ont pas de haltes mais des gares pour les Intercitys et des arrêts pour les Omnibus.

Comment: Tout ça ne répond pas vraiment à ma question et semble plutôt être en réponse à Laure, dans quel cas ce devrait être un commentaire.